Stop iOS showing file in BrowserComponent
I'm using browser component to show a web page. From this page it is possible to download a csv file. I store the file using FileSystemStorage. This works well. However on an iPhone the csv opens and is shown in the browser component as below.

I ask the user for a file name then save to file system storage. The issue is, the user does not have any way to go back from the page shown above. There is no 'Done' or share button as is normally shown when opening the file using Display.getInstance().execute(filePath) like below.

How can I stop or block the iOS device from opening or showing the csv file in the browser component?

Why not block the navigation to the CSV in general using the BrowserComponent navigation listener then download it yourself and provide your own UI to indicate that it was/is downloaded?

Hi Shai, thank you for the response. I am actually already handling the download myself using JSCallback. I actually don't want a done or share button. I need to stop the iOS device doing anything when that button is pressed. Any example would be appreciated

I eventually just avoided the issue by navigating back if the URL is unexpected after the download is complete or cancelled. I think iOS devices show some sort of preview of the file however there was no way for the user to navigate back from that preview window. Since it was only happening on the iOS device I couldn't debug it very easily.

You can control browser navigation using addBrowserNavigationCallback e.g.:
browser.addBrowserNavigationCallback(url -> {
   if(url.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")) {
       // it is crucial that this callback returns immediately and no
       // action be performed on the navigation callback thread...
       callSerially(() -> performDownloadLogic(url));
       return false;
   }
   return true;
});

